# Word for "day off between two holidays"

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a word/phrase I can use for a day off taken between two holidays?

Suppose that Tuesday and Thursday are holiday; if I take a day off on Wednesday, in Italian I would call that day *ponte* (which literally means *bridge*). Is there an equivalent phrase I can use in English?

Notice that I could talk of *ponte* also when one of the two days is a day where normally people don't go to work, for example Saturday or Sunday. I would not talk of *ponte* for myself if Tuesday and Thursday are days I don't normally work (but most of the people work), and I take a day off on Wednesday.

Comment: We don't have holidays that close together in the US. However, Thanksgiving always falls on a Thursday; when people take the following day off, I've usually heard it express something like this: “I'm going to take Friday off, and _make it a long weekend_.” The same phraseology could apply if July 4 (Independence Day) fell on a Tuesday, and someone took the preceding Monday off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a commonly used word for it, because, at least in the UK, we don't have public holidays like that. If the situation arose, we'd use *bridge*.

Comment: Maybe in UK there are not two holidays in the same week separated by a working day, but Christmas could fall on Thursday. As far as I recall, the day after Christmas is not holiday, in UK.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The day after Christmas is Boxing Day, and is a public holiday in the UK.

Comment: @kiamlaluno. As Matt says.

Comment: @Matt Oh, that is Boxing Day. From the name, I would have thought to a different holiday. `:)` Isn't there any UK holiday that can fall on a Thursday?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Boxing Day is one such example that could fall on a Thursday. Also Christmas Day and New Year's Day.